# How to launch applications in 32 bit from Terminal in Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, terminal, 32-bit

Like a lot of people, I have some issues with launching my applications in 32 bit mode, because of the far-from-perfect LCC 3.1 driver for my Logitech di novo edge keyboard. Basically, I am not able to use the correct keyboard layout when in 64 bit mode (my layout changes when I switch applications which is *very* annoying).

So I am forced to launch my applications in 32 bits.

Can I do this from the terminal with an `exec` command? Checking the 'launch application in 32 bit mode' seems to have no effect (but it does work from the gui).

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I should have precised I am trying to make the `mvim`script (given in macvim) launch macvim in 32 bit. So solutions based on `open`, although launching the application in 32 bit, are not what I am looking for, because they seem not to correctly handle pipes and argument passing.

Answer (score 6):

Use `arch -i386 macvim`

Comment: It works (it launches the application in 32 bits), but pipelining does not seem to work : `echo foo | arch -i386 /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/MacVim` brings an empty MacVim.

Comment: After a bit of head-scratching and mulling over a downloaded copy of MacVim, I found the answer -- MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/MacVim apparently never reads from stdin, you need to use MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim instead (check the binary= line in mvim) and add the flags "-g -".  Try: `echo foo | arch -i386 /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim -g -`

Comment: my macvim screen remains desperately blank, and for some reason that's the 64b version that's being launched...

Comment: It looks like the Vim binary (running in 32-bit mode) is launching the MacVim binary (which runs in 64-bit, no matter what Vim was running in). Yeesh. Ok, I'm gonna recommend either Debilski's route (but replacing the original binaries with the stripped version), or just downloading the precompiled MacVim-7_2-stable-1_2 from Google Code (which is compiled 32-bit only).

Comment: This works with OSX Lion.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `open` command in Terminal instead of `exec`.

I just tried it with Chess.app and `open` takes notice of the 'Open in 32-bit mode` checkbox.

Comment: yes, but infortunately, `open` unfortunately doesn't redirect the standard input /error as `exec`does

Answer (score 2):

If it’s only about MacVim, you can strip the 64-bit code from the binary with `ditto`.

```
ditto --arch i386 /Applications/Utilities/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/MacVim /Applications/Utilities/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/MacVim_i386
exec /Applications/Utilities/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/MacVim_i386
```

I just tried it and it seems to work. Maybe you can even pipe through `ditto`, but I have my doubts.

Comment: I couldn't make it work either: it seems that when you pass the -g option to Vim (`exec /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim_i386 -g`), it forks in 64 bit mode.